# python pandas loop append dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, loops, data-science

I am attempting to create a loop that will analyze time series data and average the data 'per day' in a seperate pandas dataframe.

For now if I make up some fake time series data to get a working program:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

time = pd.date_range('6/28/2013', periods=2000, freq='5min')
data = pd.Series(np.random.randint(100, size=2000), index=time)
```

Im stuck in the loop portion of trying to iterate over each value on the data set. I think I need to create a blank pandas dataframe `obs` and then just keep appending this data frame thru the entire dataset... Any tips help! Thanks

```
obs = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(len(data)):
    dfDaily = data.groupby(data.index.day).mean()
    obs.append(dfDaily)
```

Comment: Do you _really_ need to create the DataFrame on a loop? If not, you can do something like `dfDaily=data.resample('D').mean()`

Comment: That worked thanks for the tip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are trying to achieve?

```
>>> data.groupby(data.index.date).mean()
2013-06-28    51.211806
2013-06-29    50.256944
2013-06-30    53.902778
2013-07-01    50.555556
2013-07-02    48.302083
2013-07-03    48.538194
2013-07-04    50.522059
dtype: float64
```